# How to integrate scorm to an LMS (sharepoint)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, integration, scorm

i have an LMS coded with Sharepoint & c#.
i want to use scorm, but i dont have any idea about scorm and scorm integration.
Also i want that is playable on mobile devices. What should i know about scorm scorm?
Can anyone explain it or give some advices about this? or is there any documentation about this? i really dont know anything about this, thats why i want a document step by step.
Also i really dont want to work with flash, flash contents or flash players etc..

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a learning kit that might help http://slk.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The best place to dive into what SCORM is and how it works is the [SCORM Explained](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/) section of scorm.com

Microsoft published a Sharepoint Learning Kit that includes a basic SCORM player. I've heard mixed reviews, but if you are just looking for the basics it might not be a bad solution.

If that doesn't work out for you, then [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/) is where I'd look next.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but scorm.com is not usefull i think, i didnt understand anything about using scorm from there. i need step by step explaination.